# What would happen if invalid WAR file is uploaded to Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, war, uploading

What would happen if invalid WAR file is uploaded to Google App Engine?

I can do try to upload myself but I can't seem to upload because of my network connection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would just give you a error message after trying to upload it.

Comment: Hi tr4656, I'm sorry to ask you this...but what kind of error message?
Thanks!